Reset Ubuntu dotfiles?
I recently ran and installed someone's dotfiles (it was like a popular one, from awesome-dotfiles github repo) and my terminal seems like this

How can I reset it?

Two options: 1. Find the exact script you installed and figure out a way to uninstall it (either there is an uninstall script in the github repo or you can create and issue in github and ask how to uninstall). Without more details about what you did, we cannot help you reverting the changes. 2. Create a new user, and delete your existing user. It will automatically load the default configurations.

Most likely that's coming from your ~/.bashrc file ... You can back it up with mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak and install the original one with cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc ... Close and open your terminal to see if it worked.

I did this but nothing happened? I restarted terminal and PC.

There isn't a uninstall script in it + I lost it I guess
